# Ambiguity about $geoNear in aggregate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, geojson

I'm setting up a location based project where I'm working with GeoJSON. I've used $geoNear and I'm pretty familiar with it. Now I've reached a situation where I need to check from a list of documents that whether they fall in the maxDistance or not. 
And the challenge here is maxDistance is not predefined. It varies from document to document and being stored in the document.

This is something like every store to be shown up in the map that is setup by the user to be informed when the user is in range of the told distance of store. And user defines the distance. 
For example: User adds a location and describe a distance for it. Now the usecase will be notify user on map if he reaches in the defined distance for that location.

```
Location.aggregate([
{
    $geoNear: {
    spherical: true,
    near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ user.location.coordinates[0], user.location.coordinates[1] ] },
    maxDistance: {Needs to be taken from each Location document and each document should be filtered against own distance},
    distanceField: 'dist.calculated'
   }
 }
```

The worst approach is I load all the documents with distance and then loop through to check if they fall in their specific distance but I want to follow a good and professional approach. Any clues?

Here is location's schema:

```
Location = new Schema({
  location: {
        type: {
          type: String,
          enum: ['Point'], 
        },
        coordinates: {
          type: [Number]
        }
    },
  distance: {
    type: Number
  }
})
```

And I'm simply passing user's current coordinates to the query.

Comment: So basically you want to check for the distance whether it is in the range of that field which is saved in the document itself? Where the coordinates come from?

Comment: coordinates are also there in GoeJSON in Location collection. Also user has its own coordinates to compare with.

Comment: Still not clear. coordinates should be passed by the user. Isn't it?

Comment: yes it is. coordinates are passed by the user.

Comment: Here are user's coordinates -> user.location.coordinates[0], user.location.coordinates[1]

Comment: I have shows in above code.

Comment: Could you show where you made looping? The javascript code.

Comment: I didn't loop yet though. It will be my last option to do so.

Comment: Ok what is the range through which document will be filtered? Suppose `distance` in the document is `100` and distance field is 10`? what should be the filtered criteria?

Comment: the filtered criteria should be distance in the document is 100 then if distanceField is less than 100 I should get that doc.

Comment: if distance in another document is 150 then if distanceField is less than 150 I should get that doc too.

Comment: Is there any issue with the below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
Location.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "spherical": true,
    "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ user.location.coordinates[0], user.location.coordinates[1] ] },
    "distanceField": "dist.calculated"
  }},
  { "$match": { "$expr": { "$lte": ["$distanceField", "$distance"] }}}
])
```